# SML produces compiler bug

Tags: compiler-errors, sml

This

```
- fun dist (x:real, y:real):real*real = (Math.sqrt (x*x+y*y), Math.abs(x-y));
```

produces an error

```
Error: unbound variable or constructor: abs in path Math.abs
```

So even with a self-made version of `abs` I get

```
- fun abs (n : real)  = if n <0.0 then ~n else n;
val abs = fn : real -> real
- fun dist (x:real, y:real) = (Math.sqrt (x*x + y*y), abs (x-y));
val dist = fn : real * real -> real * real
- dist (2.0, 3.0);
Error: Compiler bug: PPObj: ppFields in ppval.sml
```

I was following along in [Programming in Standard ML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/isml/book.pdf), page 49. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What SML compiler are you using, and which version?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you've run in to [this bug](https://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=33&aid=244&atid=215). I suggest you revert to an earlier version of the compiler (your program is working for me on 110.91) and try again.

Comment: According to [smlnj.org](https://smlnj.org), "The latest release is 110.96; we believe that this version is stable, but there have been a lot of low-level changes that might have introduced bugs, so if you have any problems with the system you should report them and then revert to 110.87." But I'd probably stick with 110.79 simply because it's available precompiled in Debian/Ubuntu's package repository.

Comment: Works on Poly 5.8. My SML is 110.96. Can't get my previous SMLs to run... Complains of `~/opt/sml110.85/bin/.run/run.x86-linux: not found` when it's right there...

Comment: That could be a different problem. Did you try to `ldd ~/opt/sml110.85/bin/.run/run.x86-linux: not found`? Anyway, this issue is probably not the right place to discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I responded with saying that the library function is called [`Real.abs`](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/real.html#SIG:REAL.abs:VAL) and not `Math.abs` and remarked that it handles several corner cases (±infinity, ±0.0, ±NaN) that your custom `abs` function does not.

If, however, you would like to try and make your own `abs` function work, I've tried to run your program in SML/NJ 110.79 (`apt install smlnj`), Poly/ML 5.7.1 (`apt install polyml`) and Moscow ML 2.10 (http://try.mosml.org) without getting the bug. Perhaps you're running a flakey version, or you're experiencing 64-bit issues?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but regrettably I'm allergic to cats, cute as they may be. Still getting error, though....

Comment: Yes, this must be a bug. Works fine with poly.